# Javascript not working in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple extension for google chrome. I am including the code that I have used. But the script included is not working.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <script src="ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <button id='test'>Test</button>
<body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Demo Extension",
  "description": "Demo Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Demo",
      "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://localhost; object-src 'self'",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**ext.js**

```
function clickHandler(e) {
  alert('its working');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentReady', function () {

  document.querySelector('button')
          .addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You missed the end tag for body. Is it same in your extension too? </body>

Comment: It's `DOMContentLoaded` rather than `DOMContentReady`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's DOMContentLoaded rather than DOMContentReady - devnull69